# Inserting a value - Oracle sql date field format

Tags: sql, oracle, date

From what I have seen so far, when inserting into a table that has date value such as "27-10-2004", the following format DD-MON-YYYY is used

```
insert into tableName values('27-Oct-2004')
```

Is it possible to insert the date in its original format '27-10-2004' into the table? In general how many variations of this date may be considered correct for inserting into tables (this is without using any built-in functions, just SQL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `date` literal in Oracle:

```
insert into tableName
    values (DATE '2004-10-27');
```

This defines a date constant using the ISO standard format YYYY-MM-DD.

If you wanted to use a specific format -- which I wouldn't recommend -- then you can convert to a `date` using `to_date()`:

```
insert into tableName
    values (to_date('27-10-2004', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

Any particular string that you use is interpreted based on system settings, so it can vary by language and geography.

Note:  When inserting a value, you should include the column names.  I assume that your code is just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Your comments assume that the OP is typing a date at his keyboard. The "specific format - which I wouldn't recomment" makes no sense if the OP is receiving data from some source, and the dates come in as strings in a format the OP has no control over.

Comment: Thanks, if you don't use date and to_date(), could you insert date in other formats? Or only 'DD-MON-YYYY' is allowed without any built-in functions?

Comment: @Fabiana . . . You can use whatever the default format is on the Oracle system.  The default is "DD-MON-YYYY".  But `DATE YYYY-MM-DD` should always work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How can I find out the default of my system, and how can I change it?

Comment: @Fabiana - Gordon is referring to a parameter that is used for conversions when you don't specify a format in `TO_DATE`. It is not a "default in the Oracle system" - each session has its own "default" and it can be changed during the session too. The parameter is 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT', you can see its value with `select * from v$nls_parameters` (just try it and see what it returns, you may want to learn about some of the other parameters as well; find `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and see what it is set to). And you can change it with `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='dd-mm-yyyy';` or whatever you need.

Comment: @Fabiana - two more things. First, if you try to insert a string in a `DATE` column without using `TO_DATE`, Oracle will call `TO_DATE` implicitly, and it will use `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for the conversion. Second, be advised that some, but not all, graphical user interfaces used to interact with an Oracle database have their own settings for things like date formats, and they (stupidly, if you asked me) override the database parameters, like `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. If you change `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` with `ALTER SESSION` and that doesn't work as expected, the first place to look is your GUI.

Comment: @Fabiana - this blog article (one of my favorites!) should help you better understand how oracle handles dates - and the difference between a DATE (data type) and a string representation of a date.   https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/dealing-with-dates/